# How is an electric motor conversion kit patent eligible?

Tags: patentability, eligibility

In reference to the patent: [US9102221](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9102221B1/en)

It reads like this is just a bunch of off the rack parts and a little fabrication of brackets

Answer (score 1):

What is patented is defined by the claims. In this case there is only one claim (below). One thing to remember about claims. Long complicated claims where there are a lot of specifics are usually narrow and thus easily circumvented. Short claims are generally broader. In this case, there is a very long claim with many specifics. I'm not sure why the examiner found this patent sufficiently novel, but I would say as an engineer, it should be trivial to engineer around this patent.

> 1. An internal combustion engine to electric motor conversion kit system for supporting vehicle components in operative proximity to an
>      electric direct/alternating current motor and for powering such
>      supported vehicle components from the electric direct/alternating
>      current motor, the supporting and powering being done in a safe,
>      ecological, convenient and economical manner, the system comprising,
>      in combination:
>
>    a vehicle having a plurality of wheels and an operator
>      controlled region,
>
>    the electric direct/alternating current motor being
>      within the vehicle, the electric direct/alternating current motor
>      having a forward end and a rearward end and a cylindrical side wall,
>      the electric direct/alternating current motor having a central shaft,
>      the central shaft having a rearward section within the electric
>      direct/alternating current motor and a forward section extending
>      forward of the electric direct/alternating current motor, the central
>      shaft being rotatable about a horizontal axis;
>
>    a support assembly for
>      retaining the electric direct/alternating current motor in an
>      operative position, the support assembly including a central motor
>      support and side motor supports, the motor mounts, the motor mounts
>      coupling the central and side motor supports to the vehicle, the
>      support assembly also including two vertically extending lateral
>      brackets coupling the side wall of the electric direct/alternating
>      current motor to the central motor support;
>
>    a primary bracket formed
>      with a vertically oriented first section removably coupled to the
>      forward end of the electric direct/alternating current motor, the
>      primary bracket formed with a vertically oriented second section
>      rearwardly of and above the first section, the primary bracket formed
>      with a third section perpendicular to and joining the first and second
>      sections, an aperture in the first section in a key-hole shape for the
>      passage of wires and the central shaft; vehicle components including
>      at least one alternator and at least one air conditioning compressor
>      and at least one power steering pump, the vehicle components being
>      rotatably coupled to the second section of the primary bracket;
>
>    a motion imparting assembly for driving the vehicle components, the
>      motion imparting assembly including at least one drive pulley secured
>      to and rotatable with the central shaft, the motion imparting assembly
>      also including at least one driven pulley on the at least one
>      alternator, at least one driven pulley on the at least one air
>      conditioning compressor, and at least one driven pulley on the at
>      least one power steering pump, the motion imparting assembly also
>      including at least one idler pulley and at least one tensioning
>      pulley, the motion imparting assembly also including at least one belt
>      movable in a vertical plane and operatively coupling the at least one
>      drive pulley and the at least one driven pulleys and the at least one
>      idler and tensioning pulleys;
>
>    a supplemental bracket secured to the
>      second section of the primary bracket at an elevation above the third
>      section, cable lines mounted on the supplemental bracket to increase
>      and decrease the speed of the electric direct/alternating current
>      motor and the vehicle; a radiator and a cooling fan, the radiator and
>      cooling fan being positioned forward of the electric
>      direct/alternating current motor to facilitate cooling of the electric
>      direct/alternating current motor and the vehicle components;
>
>    and a
>      battery pack and controller in the vehicle for powering and
>      controlling the electric direct/alternating current motor.